# How to install python-dev without yum

Tags: python, mysql-python

When I install the Mysql-python-1.2.5,it failed that it cannot find the file Python.h,so I need to install the python-dev-2.6.6 package ,but my centos cannot connect to the Internet,so I need the tar.gz file,who can tell  me where to download the source package,thanks